# Include ListHeaderComponent in numColumns - React-Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Does anyone know how I can include the header of a flatlist in the columns? 
For example, in the image below I would like "Design" to follow "New +" in the same row.

[Example Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A76eo.png)

Here is my code in render:

```
<FlatList
  data={goalItems}
  extraData={this.props}
  renderItem={this._renderGoal}
  ListHeaderComponent={this._renderGoalHeader}
  keyExtractor={item => item.goal_id}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
  numColumns={2}
/>
```

and in _renderGoal:

```
_renderGoal = ({ item }) => (
  <TouchableOpacity 
    onPress={() => this.openOptions(item)} 
    style={{ padding: 10 }}>
    <Bubble>
      <Text style={[styles.normalText]}>{item.name}</Text>
      <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>{formatSeconds(item.total_time)}</Text>
      </View>
    </Bubble>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

and in _renderGoalHeader:

```
_renderGoalHeader = () => (
  <TouchableOpacity 
    onPress={() => this.openAddGoal()} 
    style={{ padding: 10 }}>
    <Bubble style={[styles.newGoal]}>
      <Text style={[styles.touchableText]}>New +</Text>
    </Bubble>
  </TouchableOpacity>
)
```

Thanks in advance.

As a temporary fix, I removed numColums from the flatList and added the following:

```
contentContainerStyle={{ flexWrap: 'wrap', flexDirection: 'row', width: 345 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would love to be proven wrong here, but as far as I can tell, this cannot be done using `numColumns`. There is a workaround which I'll list at the end, but first the reasoning:

**Explanation**

I ran into this same issue but with the footer and did a code dive into the React Native source to see what was happening. First thing I did was use the inspector and I noticed that the header and footer of a `FlatList` are wrapped in a `View` while each row of columns is wrapped in `CellRenderer > View`. This is the first clue that `FlatList` does not account for headers and footers in `numColumns`. This is problematic because `FlatList` [does not support masonry type layouts](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#numcolumns). This hints at the fact that there are many assumptions being made about how they are handling rendering the rows - that is, items are separated into rows to be rendered.

With these clues, I went into the source and found that `FlatList` passes its own [custom `renderItem`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/6f007e8957c9bf5652b0184cba65f385050a8236/Libraries/Lists/FlatList.js#L604) down to `VirtualizedList`. Meanwhile, `ListHeaderComponent` and `ListFooterComponent` are passed down as is. They are never used in `FlatList`. Not a good sign as you'll see that the aforementioned `_renderItem` is what handles grouping the items together into columns to render using `flexDirection: 'row'` and whatever is passed down with `columnWrapperStyle`.

But perhaps VirtualizedList is smart enough to combine the header and footer into `data` that gets passed into `renderItem`?

Sadly, this is not the case. If you follow the code in `VirtualizedList`, you'll eventually see all the logic get played out in `render()` where:

1. a [`cells` array](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/6f007e8957c9bf5652b0184cba65f385050a8236/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L731) is created
2. that first has the [header pushed into it](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/6f007e8957c9bf5652b0184cba65f385050a8236/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L744)
3. followed by all of the `data` [pushed into it](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/6f007e8957c9bf5652b0184cba65f385050a8236/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L762) via its [`_pushCells` helper method](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/6f007e8957c9bf5652b0184cba65f385050a8236/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L639)

   - This is where `CellRenderer` appears;
   - hence why headers and footers are not wrapped by this whereas the rows are.
   - This is also where [`FlatList`s _renderItem is used](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/6f007e8957c9bf5652b0184cba65f385050a8236/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L1617) explaining why you get `numColumns` number of items wrapped in a `CellRenderer`.
4. and then finished with the [footer being pushed](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/6f007e8957c9bf5652b0184cba65f385050a8236/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L869) in the same manner as the header.
5. This `cells` array of React components is then eventually [cloned](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/6f007e8957c9bf5652b0184cba65f385050a8236/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L898) which helps with things such as keeping scroll position.
6. And finally [rendered](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/6f007e8957c9bf5652b0184cba65f385050a8236/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L910).

Do to this implementation, you will always get a fixed `CellRenderer` component which prevents headers and footers from being included as part of `numColumns`.

**Workaround** (not recommended)

If you've used React Native prior to `FlatList` being released, you'll know that one old workaround was to be very careful with your dimensions and use `flexWrap: 'wrap'`. It's actually [documented within the source code as it will spit out a warning](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/6f007e8957c9bf5652b0184cba65f385050a8236/Libraries/Lists/VirtualizedList.js#L713) if you use this method of handling columns. Do note that it is **NOT** recommended to do this (I believe performance and perhaps scroll position may be some of the reasons against using this method).

If you are willing to do this though, add these styles to your `contentContainerStyle`:

```
flexDirection: 'row',
flexWrap: 'wrap',
// You'll probably also want this for handling empty cells at the end:
justifyContent: 'flex-start',
```

and remove the `numColumns` prop. Then make sure to manually size your component dimensions to get the correct looking column style layout you desire. This should allow your header and footer to render as part of the columns.

Comment: for future reference I would recommend checking out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62848058/styling-react-native-flatlist .

Answer (score -2):

If you want to do it with numOfColumns, than use flexDirection:'row' within your header component

```
_renderGoalHeader = () => (
 return(
  <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
  <TouchableOpacity 
    onPress={() => this.openAddGoal()} 
    style={{ flex:1, padding: 10, }}>
    <Bubble style={[styles.newGoal]}>
      <Text style={[styles.touchableText]}>New +</Text>
    </Bubble>
  </TouchableOpacity>
 <View>
 <View style={{flex:1}}/> //this view is just to cover half width
 );
)
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, and also render methods have to be wrapped in a single tag